# Which is a better method to combine probability in Naive Bayes?

Tags: bayesian, naive-bayes, bayes

The Wikipedia article "Naive Bayes Spam Filtering" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_spam_filtering#Mixed_methods)
mentions two methods of combining probability that addresses underflow concern. I rarely use the inverse chi square as the ln difference method is simpler and more intuitive to me. (Subtraction logs is division, adding logs is multiplication...)
When testing the chi square method, I get almost nearly the same result.

When would I use the chi square approach? What is the justification for it?

[image: Chi Square]

[image: log summation]